# GPGME: Best practices for automatic decryption in rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, gnupg, gpgme

I'd like to be able ato implement the following behaviour :

- An admin should be asked the passphrase to the GPG production key during the Rails server startup in production
- The passphrase should not be stored anywhere other than RAM
- Decryption capabilities should not be available in rake tasks or rails console

A gpg-agent seems out of the question, since any process launched by the same user the rails server runs with would be able to decrypt content.

A passphrase callback for the GPGME class asking for the passphrase seems to be the best solution (although tricky to implement because of the start-stop-daemon wrapper in /etc/init.d/unicorn which grabs stdin).

Am I missing something ? Are there any security holes with such a setup ? What would be a better solution ? Many thanks.